# c++ stl associative container & user defined type

Tags: c++, stl

I classified c++ stl associative container by following criteria **(set, map) (normal, multi) (ordered, unordered)**.
There are 8 cases (2 * 2 * 2).

1. set

   - multiset

     - unordered_multiset
     - (ordered)multiset
   - set

     - unordered_set
     - (ordered)set
2. map

   - multimap

     - unordered_multimap
     - (ordered)multimap
   - map

     - unordered_map
     - (ordered)map

I want to ensure myself that for each container, in order to use user defined class as key which functions should be defined. Below is my answer to my question.

1. set

   - multiset

     - unordered_multiset : `hash function`, `comparison function for equality`
     - (ordered)multiset : `comparison function for <`
   - set

     - unordered_set : `hash function`, `comparison function for equality`
     - (ordered)set : `comparison function for <`
2. map

   - multimap

     - unordered_multimap : `hash function`, `comparison function for equality`
     - (ordered)multimap : `comparison function for <`
   - map

     - unordered_map : `hash function`, `comparison function for equality`
     - (ordered)map : `comparison function for <`

Is it correct?

Comment: simpler classification: unordered: hash and eq; ordered: less than

Comment: The key doesn't need to provide those operators, you can always pass in a function object that does it.

Comment: thanks for your(bolov, Rakete1111) comment.

Comment: Doesn't have to be less than either. It only has to be a strict weak ordering. Plenty of Q&As on this site about that.

Comment: [The manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) is probably the best place to check your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is completely correct.

Comment: Well, the OP doesn't need to provide a less than operation per se.  The could also use greater than as you just need a comarator that provides a *strict weak ordering*